# ive been following a tutorial on minecraft java edition modding but when i want wo do the Block registry it will give me random errors that i cant fix

Tags: java

```
package com.schnoel.testmod.init;

import java.util.function.Function;

import com.google.common.base.Supplier;
import com.schnoel.testmod.TestMod;

import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.world.item.Item.Properties;
import net.minecraft.world.item.Items;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.state.BlockBehaviour;
import net.minecraft.world.level.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.world.level.material.MaterialColor;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.RegistryObject;

    public class BlockInit {
        public static final DeferredRegister <Block> BLOCKS = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.BLOCKS, TestMod.MOD_ID);
    
        public static final DeferredRegister <Item> ITEMS = ItemInit.ITEMS;
    
        public static final RegistryObject<Block> EXAMPLE_BLOCK = register("example_block",
                () -> new Block(BlockBehaviour.Properties.of(Material.METAL, MaterialColor.COLOR_GREEN),
                object -> () -> new Item(new Item.Properties().tab(testmod.T_TAB)));        
    
        private static<T extends Block> RegistryObject<T> register(final String name, final Supplier<? extends T> block){
            return BLOCKS.register(name, block);
        }
    
        private static <T extends Block> RegistryObject<T> register(final String name, final Supplier<? extends T> block, Function<RegistryObject<T>> block) {
            RegistryObject<T> obj = registerBlock(name, block);
            return obj;
        }

}
```

```
line 14: Syntax error, insert ")" to complete ClassInstanceCreationExpression
    
line 18: Incorrect number of arguments for type Function<T,R>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <RegistryObject<T>>
    
line 18: Duplicate parameter block (idk what im supposed to do here)

line 19: T cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: Which ones are lines 14 and 18?

Comment: "Duplicate parameter `block`" tells you that you named two different variables with the same name, `block`. Look at the method signature for the second `register`: this is something you cannot do. The other error (line "14") is because of the imbalanced parenthesis on your `EXAMPLE_BLOCK` value.

Comment: Also, please read [ask]. Especially the section about titles.

Comment: Line 14 appears to be an `import` statement.

Comment: line 14: object -> () -> new Item(new Item.Properties().tab(testmod.T_TAB)));

Comment: lines 18 & 19: private static <T extends Block> RegistryObject<T> register(final String name, final Supplier<? extends T> block, Function<RegistryObject<T>> block) {
            RegistryObject<T> obj = registerBlock(name, block);

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis here: `() -> new Block(BlockBehaviour.Properties.of(Material.METAL, MaterialColor.COLOR_GREEN),`. That throws off the parsing and causes all the other errors.

Comment: where exactly i cant find it

Comment: If you're using an IDE and click on a parenthesis, it will typically highlight the matching (open or closed) parenthesis for it. Notice that the last parenthesis in your whole `EXAMPLE_BLOCK` value matches up with the `(` after `new Block` (So then `register(...` has no closing parenthesis). Additionally, a `Function<T,R>` has two generic values, you haven't specified the input type (and if it has none, then it is a `Supplier<T>`. If it doesn't return anything, it would be a `Consumer<T>`, where `T` is the type you are working with).

Comment: i have added the bracket. now it says: The constructor Block(BlockBehaviour.Properties, (<no type> object) -> {}) is undefined

Comment: You added it in the wrong place. Look at my comment and count the parentheses.

Comment: i have added it behind TestMod.T_TAB

Comment: Well why did you add it there? It's not going to work if you put things in random places.

Comment: im sorry im new to java and have no idea where to put that )

Comment: Like I said, You're missing a parenthesis here `() -> new Block(BlockBehaviour.Properties.of(Material.METAL, MaterialColor.COLOR_GREEN),` at the end. If you don't know Java, you're not going to be able to do any modding. You're going to be stumbling blindly.

Comment: that doesnt make sense and messes it up even more